# Access Query with a textbox as criteria for a string OR int

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria

I'm working with an issue that I can't seem to get around.  I have an Access query where I'm checking multiple columns against a criteria of a single textbox value.  Everything works great with the first 3 columns.  They're all strings.

```
SELECT Req.Ctrl, Vend.VendNick, Req.CSCReq, Req.PO, Req.Status, Line.Quote
FROM Line INNER JOIN (Vend INNER JOIN Req ON Vend.[VendID] = Req.[Vend]) 
ON Line.Ctrl = Req.Ctrl
WHERE (((Req.CSCReq)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((Req.PO)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((Line.Quote)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2]));
```

When I add the 4th column, I get the error "The expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex..."

```
SELECT Req.Ctrl, Vend.VendNick, Req.CSCReq, Req.PO, Req.Status, Line.Quote
FROM Line INNER JOIN (Vend INNER JOIN Req ON Vend.[VendID] = Req.[Vend]) 
ON Line.Ctrl = Req.Ctrl
WHERE (((Req.CSCReq)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((Req.PO)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((Line.Quote)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR
(((Req.Ctrl)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2]));
```

I'm assuming this is because the 4th column is an int and access is not defining the parameter for the value of the textbox correctly for this particular column.  Is there any way I can address this at the column level of the query or in sql so that the first 3 still see the value as a string, but the 4th sees the value as an int?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

instead for converting your column to string for every row in your table to be compared with the textbox value, do the opposite using `CInt`. it will be way more efficient:

```
(((Req.Ctrl)=CInt([Forms]![Index]![Box2])));
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined both of your answers and a little google to help me get where I was trying to go.  Thanks very much for the quick responses.  Ted's answer made the 4th column work, but the other 3 started failing with the same error.  JohnHC's did the same. Below is what finally worked.

```
SELECT Req.Ctrl, Vend.VendNick, Req.CSCReq, Req.PO, Req.Status, Line.Quote
FROM Line INNER JOIN (Vend INNER JOIN Req ON Vend.[VendID] = Req.[Vend]) 
ON Line.Ctrl = Req.Ctrl
WHERE (((Line.Quote)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((Req.PO)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((Req.CSCReq)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2])) OR 
(((CVar([Req].[Ctrl]))=[Forms]![Index]![Box2]));
```

For some reason CVar made everything start clicking... Not sure why, but it works.

Comment: Take another look ar @Ted's answer i.e. cast the parameter to integer to match the type of the column (especially if you don't know why you your answer works :).

Answer (score -1):

Use the STR() function:

```
str(Req.Ctrl)=[Forms]![Index]![Box2]
```

As an aside, I hate MS Access and its overuse of brackets...

Comment: it will be very expensive to convert all `Req.Ctrl` to string to compare it with the texbox. it's always better to convert the input value